# How to pass data from div like from input in nodejs

Tags: node.js, quill

I want to pass data from quill editor but problem is that editor is div. In which is another div created after pageload.

Handlebars

```
<!-- Create the editor container -->
    <div id="editor" name="body">

    <div class="another div created after page load">
    </div>

    </div>
```

But problem is that i cant probably pass data from div it needs to be input but i have no idea how can i make it.

Controller for articles

```
exports.articleAdd = function (req, res) {
    let article = new Article();
    article.heading = req.body.heading;
    article.author = req.user.firstname;
    article.body = req.body.body;

    article.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: But HTML is in the front (browser) and Node runs on the server, are you aware of this? Node has no direct access to the HTML code, since these two environments run on two different machines

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes you are right but still dont know how can this be solved :/

Comment: Well apparently, the problem is more than just passing data. It seems to me that you're not aware of the difference between client-side and server-side, are you? You have to pass data from the front (browser) to the server, using for instance an Ajax call. Then receive it on the server with a route, _then_ save it to the database. [Differences between Client-side and Server-side Scripting](https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/ClientSide01CD/page_18.htm)

Comment: I am confused now. I understand that it goes from user(browser) to the server. I have route for this thats ok. But i am using MVC so i have model view and controller.
I can pass data when body is input but cant when body is div.

Comment: But i probably find what i was looking for so thank you :) https://quilljs.com/playground/#form-submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved on their official site.  https://quilljs.com/playground/#form-submit